# how to remove the unused genreated require when use protobuf anotations

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, proto, protobuf.js, grpc-node

```
package usegogo.api.v1;

import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
import "google/protobuf/duration.proto";
import "google/protobuf/field_mask.proto";
import "gogoproto/gogo.proto";

option (gogoproto.marshaler_all) = false;
```

I use gogoproto to generate go codes.
But when I generate nodejs code, there is a `var gogoproto_gogo_pb = require('../../../gogoproto/gogo_pb.js');`

this is generated because i use `import "gogoproto/gogo.proto";`

is there any way to let protoc ignore the the `import "gogoproto/gogo.proto";`  sine i don't use this when i genreate nodejs code.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Protoc will actually generate `gogo_pb.js` if you point it to `gogo.proto` like you do with your other proto files.